# How many relations R are there on a set such that at least one ordered pair in R has a(a particular element) as its first element?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I don't know what to do with this question...spacially the part that says "at least"...
I know that the number of possible relations on a set with n elements is:
2^(n^2)
Can anyone tell me how can I answer this problem?
Thank you so much!

Comment: The number of times "at least one" thing occurs, is:  The total number of possible cases (where the thing may or may not occur any number of times) minus the number of times the thing *never* occurs.  What's left is the number of times the thing occurs at least once.  SO... The number of all relations minus the number of relations where there are *no* ordered pairs starting with $a$ = the number of relations where there is at least one such ordered pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of times "at least one" thing occurs, is:  The total number of possible cases (where the thing may or may not occur any number of times) minus the number of times the thing *never* occurs.  What's left is the number of times the thing occurs at least once.  SO... The number of all relations minus the number of relations where there are *no* ordered pairs starting with $a$ = the number of relations where there is at least one such ordered pair.

......

If the set has $n$ elements and $a \in$ the set:

There are $n\times n=n^2$ ordered pairs  $1\times n=n$ of them have have $a$ as their first element and $(n-1)\times n = n(n-1)$ of them do *not* have $a$ as their first elements.

......

So the number of relations where any ordered pair may or may not occur is $2^{n^2}$.

And the number of relations where any ordered pair $(a,x)$ can *never* occur is $2^{n(n-1)}$.

And the number of relations where an ordered pair $(a,x)$ must occur at least once is:

$2^{n^2} - 2^{n(n-1)}$.

That's it.

Comment: Your explanation was SO helpful!I completely understand the meaning of "at least" now!THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a set with $n$ elements. You already know that there are $2^{n^2}$ possible relations on $A$. Now fix a particular $a\in A$. Instead of trying to count directly the relations on $A$ that **do** contain one or more ordered pairs with $a$ as first element, try counting the relations that do **not** contain such an ordered pair. That is, you want to calculate the number of relations $R\subseteq A\times A$ such that for each $x\in A$, the ordered pair $\langle a,x\rangle$ is **not** in $R$.

HINT: This says that $R\cap(\{a\}\times A)=\varnothing$, i.e., that $R\subseteq(A\setminus\{a\})\times A$.

Comment: Thanks...actually I was thinking the same thing...but I didn't understand the hint part that you explained!and I think I'm a bit more comfortable with matrices.but thanks anyway!

Comment: @YasamanFarhangi: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If we take the matrix representation of a relation $R$, the relations where $(a,x)$ is not in $R$ for any $x$ and the specified element $a$ are those with the row corresponding to $a$ completely blank. This still leaves $n^2-n$ cells to be filled as we please. So the number of relations satisfying the given conditions is the complement, or $2^{n^2}-2^{n^2-n}=2^{n^2-n}(2^n-1)$.

Comment: Thank you...now I have a better understanding of this question when I consider it as a matrix!